I am getting this Error: Failed to create AR session com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableException while running AR app
Dynamite failed to load remote library
2024-04-15 11:31:23.447  8292-8292  third_part..._create.cc com.example.vrapplication            E  LoadSymbolsDynamite returning AR_ERROR_FATAL.
2024-04-15 11:31:23.447  8292-8292  third_part..._create.cc com.example.vrapplication            E  LoadSymbols returning status.
2024-04-15 11:31:23.461  8292-8292  StandardArFragment      com.example.vrapplication            E  Error: Failed to create AR session
com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableException
com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.initializeSession(BaseArFragment.java:391)
com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.onResume(BaseArFragment.java:338)
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:3205)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.resume(FragmentStateManager.java:646)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:296)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:114)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1455)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3034)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:2966)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:285)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:333)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:322)
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:245)
android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8770)
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4952)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4995)
android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:57)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:98)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: com.google.ar.core.exceptions.FatalException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at com.google.ar.core.Session.throwExceptionFromArStatus(Session.java:16)
a com.google.ar.core.Session.nativeCreateSessionAndWrapperWithFeatures(Native Method)
at com.google.ar.core.Session.(Session.java:11)
at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.createSessionWithFeatures(BaseArFragment.java:419)
at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.createSession(BaseArFragment.java:405)
at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.initializeSession(BaseArFragment.java:379)
at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.onResume(BaseArFragment.java:338) 
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:3205) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.resume(FragmentStateManager.java:646) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:296) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:114) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1455) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3034) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:2966) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:285) 
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:333) 
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:322) 
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:245) 
android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8770) 
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4952) 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4995) 
android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:57) 
android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45) 
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:180) 
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:98) 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 
I tried to build an AR app in android studio using kotlin and added all the necessary dependencies in build.gradle.kts file and added all the permission in the manifest file but still i am getting error that the AR session has failed
